# callback for beginning of controller work

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('Controller1',function(){
        getController1();
    })
    .controller('Controller2',function(){
        getController2();
    })
```

I have some $http function in service with GET:

```
.service("geInfo", function() {

    })
```

I want that my controllers will start only when i get the data of the service.
Do i have to use $q (promise), $watch or something else?
Does somebody can provide example?

Thanks!

Comment: Define what you mean by "I want that my controllers will start". A controller doesn't "start". It's instantiated by angular, and does whatever you want when instantiated. Do you want `getController1()` to be called by your controller only when the service info is available? Do you want angular to instantiate the controller only when the info is available? How are these controllers used? What does getInfo do? Be specific. Post real code instead of fake, meaningless, unrunnable code.

Answer (score 0):

You must resolve it in configuration phase:

```
    (function() {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('dashboardApp', [
                'ngRoute'
            ])
            .config(config);

            /* @ngInject */
            function config($routeProvider) {              
                   $routeProvider
                     .when("/youUrl", {
                        templateUrl: "youtTemplate.html",
                        controller: "yourController",
                        resolve: {
                           initInfo: function(infoService){
                               return infoService.getInfo();
                            }
                        }
                     });

            }
     })();
```

Now you have `initInfo` in your controller:

```
.controller('Controller2',function($scope, initInfo){
    $scope.info = initInfo;
})
```

By this way the router wont load the view until your service return initInfo.